# "like box" doesnt display content unless visitor is logged in to facebook

Tags: web, facebook-likebox

I have seen other "like boxes" of a fan page displayed on a website. I can see it without being logged in to facebook. BUT the fan page I made a "like box: for always asks me to be logged in to see the content.  What am I doing wrong here?

(now it says: Facebook Public Profile  Login to see this content)

Comment: Can you share any examples of a like box plugin seen without being logged in to Facebook?

Comment: Pretty please?  I've not seen this behaviour before.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this response for other users that come across this post.

"It seems you are using restriction on "minimum age" or "country" on your page.

That mean facebook can't display a like box, without knowing who is connected, because he can't know the age or the country of the current user."

All credit to AHWEBDEV

[Link](https://github.com/AHWEBDEV/Facebook-AWD/issues/89)